# C:[error]linked list quicksort

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

I was writing the linked list quick sort.

```
void quick(NODE low,NODE High){
NODE stan=low, serch=NULL;
int pivot,temp

if(low==end || low -> Next =high || low == high){return;}

serch=stan -> Next;
pivot= stan -> data;

while(serch != high){
    if(serch -> data <= pivot){
        if(serch != pivot){
            temp= serch -> data;
            serch -> data =stan -> next ->data; 
            stan -> next ->data=temp;
        }
        stan = stan -> Next;
    }
}   
quick(low, stan);

quick(stan -> next,end);
}
```

but

> [Error] invalid initializer
>
> [Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'if'
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] 'high' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> [Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] invalid operands to binary != (have 'NODE' and 'int')
>
> [Error] 'temp' undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'NODE')
>
> [Error] incompatible type for argument 2 of 'quick'
>
> [Note] expected 'NODE' but argument is of type 'struct NODE *'

error why?

Comment: Can you tell me which compiler you are using?

Comment: C is case sensitive. Also, what is `NODE`?

Comment: You need to understand when to use . vs - >

Comment: The latter is for pointers

Comment: You need to use the .

Comment: Use the dot and use it well

Comment: You should also show ur types to us

Comment: You cannot quick-sort a linked list in the same complexity compared to quick-sorting an array because of the time to index an element in a linked list is O(n)

Comment: missing ; after variable temp

Comment: please show a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if you can't handle compiler errors...

Answer (score 1):

1.you miss ; after `int pivot,temp`
2.`low -> Next =high`should be `low -> Next ==high` you should use `==`,
3.your parameter is `High` `void quick(NODE low,NODE High)`, but you use `high`,you should change
4.i guess `NODE`'s type is struct ,you should use `NODE.parameter`,and if you want to use `->`,you should use struct pointer ,so you need to define `NODE *`

Comment: **NODE stan=low, serch=NULL; ** invalid initalizer error in part why????

Comment: And I don't understand this part.

4.i guess NODE's type is struct ,you should use NODE.parameter,and if you want to use ->,you should use struct pointer ,so you need to define NODE *

For example, how should you define?

Comment: struct NODE * node; this is a struct pointer,and it use –> to visit the parameter,for example node–>a.struct NODE node use . to visit the parameter